# Is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nb_n$ convergent, given the series $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ and the sequence $\{b_n\}$ are convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then I can prove that the answer is yes.

However, here, $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ may be conditionally convergent, in which case I have no idea how to prove or find an example which disproves.

Please give some hint. Thank you!

Comment: What if $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $b_{n}=(-1)^{n}$?

Comment: Hi, Mr.Gandalf Sauron. The sequence $\{b_n\}$ is given to be convergent.

Comment: Hint: there are counterexamples with $a_n=b_n$

Comment: The dual of $\ell_1$ is $\ell_\infty$, so if $x = (x_n)_n$ is absolutely convergent and $y = (y_n)_n$ is bounded, then $y(x) = \sum_n x_n y_n$ is finite. As an example, take $x_n = n^{-2}$ and $y_n = 1$.

Comment: There is a special case when the conclusion follows. Namely by Abel theorem if $b_n$ is convergent and monotone, while the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Like you say, we want to consider $a_n$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is only *conditionally* convergent. So we should choose $a_n$ to be some sort of alternative sequence, like $a_n=c_n(-1)^n$ for some sequence $c_n$.

As a hint, try to make $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ be the divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_n=b_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: You are right... I have no idea what happened to my brain. I tried this but I refused myself because I think in that case the series cannot converge, but it does converge by the alternating series test... Thanks!